# Linux battery drain by Opera

Tags: linux, battery, opera

I have never installed Opera on my laptop yet when using powertop to see the battery usage of my laptop several Opera processes are shown all of which have very high battery drain.

Using `sudo find . -name Opera -print` returns nothing.

What could be calling this process and how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: `./` is the command used, this doesn't indicate that the Opera file is in that folder, run `sudo find / -name Opera -print` to do a full filesystem sweep instead

Comment: What does `pstree` show? Please don't answer in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/740345/edit) the question to add new info. Also please don't post textual output as images, but copy-paste directly to the question. If the output is long, you can upload it to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) and add the link to the question.

Comment: Running `ls -l /proc/<PID>/exe` should tell you the location of the executable being run. Running `ps -ef` will also show you what the parent process is. Divide and conquer. It's possible that the exe has been deleted and you are crypto mining on 12 cpu cores.

Comment: flatpak? snap? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some files in my `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` were not being deleted on reboot. Each reboot instead caused these files to launch additional Opera processeses. After thoroughly cleaning these folders the `./Opera` process is gone.